# Multiple CSS backgrounds, colour over image, ignored

Tags: firefox, css, background-color

What's wrong with this multiple background CSS line. Firefox 4 ignores it (as it does when there's a syntax error).

```
background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2), url("static/menubg.jpg");
```

Comment: Do you have any other background related tags in your css?

Comment: @Arjan: I had a `background-size` to scale the image, but I removed it and tested that before posting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for `background` in CSS3 Backgrounds is `[ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>`, which means zero or more `<bg-layer>s` and then a single `<final-bg-layer>`, separated from each other by commas.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

A `<final-bg-layer>` is defined as:

```
<final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || 
                   <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2} ||
                   <'background-color'>
```

whereas a `<bg-layer>` is:

```
 <bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]? ||
              <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2}
```

(both definitions at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#ltbg-layergt ).

Or in simple terms, only the lowest background layer can include a background color.  So yes, your CSS is in fact a syntax error.

Oh, and looks like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/multiple_backgrounds had some errors in it.  I've fixed them.

Comment: Have a +1 for a great reference; I hadn't thought to look for an authoritative source for my answer.

Comment: The "live demonstration" on that MDC page doesn't seem to be working since your changes.

Comment: Indeed.  And for extra fun, none of the things I changed should have affected that, _and_ reverting to the working revision doesn't work: the wiki is claiming the text is now the same as the working revision, but the actual markup it produces is clearly different.  I mailed the wiki maintainer.  I hate wikis.   :(

Comment: Hmm, so if I want to tint a background image a need to lay a repeated 1x1 transparent pixel image over it? What a bummer, but oh well.

Comment: Yeah, there's no really good support for that in CSS3 Backgrounds.  You could use a data: URI for the 1x1 thing...

Comment: How about defining a uniform translucent linear gradient as one of your background images?

Comment: Yup using a gradient works.  You need to put the gradient BEFORE the image though in the multiple-background syntax.

Comment: F*** W3C! I need to make a nice transition on background image load (where bg-color of the first layer would become transparent) and they ruined it. I don't want to mess my code with hard-to-do and ugly javascript walkarounds! Sometimes I think that guys from W3C never tried to make a web.

Answer (score 10):

The solutions is using:

```
{-moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%), url(bg.png) repeat 0 0;}
```

instead of:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should note that because gradients are treated as images it is acceptable and works to put in a gradient that has the same top and bottom colour.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2) url("static/menubg.jpg");` without the `,`

Comment: That's when you use a background image with a colour as fallback. I'm attempting multiple backgrounds: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/multiple_backgrounds

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough it seems to come down to the order of the parameters; the background-image *then* background-color:

```
background: url('http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar.png') no-repeat 50% 50%, rgba(255,180,0,0.8);
```

Works ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rZqwv/2/)), while background-color *then* background-image:

```
background: rgba(255,180,0,0.8), url('http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

Does not ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZqwv/1/)).

The above tested on Chromium 11 and Firefox 4, both on Ubuntu 11.04.

---

**Edited** to note that this does, indeed, come down to the order; as definitively answered in [@Boris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851597/multiple-css-backgrounds-colour-over-image-ignored/5852324#5852324).

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Oscar's nice solution (thanks!), here is how I implemented it using SASS/Compass to automate browser prefixing

```
@include background( linear-gradient( color-stops(rgba(255, 66, 78, 0.25), rgba(255, 66, 78, 0.25)) ), image-url('/img/cardboard_flat.png') );
```

This supports Webkit, Firefox, but not IE9 (because of the gradient). Then I remembered the awesome compass rgbapng Ruby gem for generating PNGs: https://github.com/aaronrussell/compass-rgbapng

```
@include background( png_base64( rgba(255, 66, 78, 0.25) ), image-url('/img/cardboard_flat.png') );
```

Now, this supports IE9+ and the rest of the browsers that support multiple backgrounds.

If you still need IE8 support, you could either use a multi-background polyfill, or style an ::after pseudo element and absolutely position it, with a z-index of -1:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url('/img/cardboard_flat.png');
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px 0;
  min-height: 100%;

  &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: png_base64( rgba(255, 66, 78, 0.25) );
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```