# Setting opacity to background-image and background-colour

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to keep a background image 100% opacity and make the background-colour 50% opacity?

```
.smallIcons{
    background-color: #f00;
    opacity: 0.5; // 50% background
    background-image: url(../twiter.png); // 100% here
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You basically want an opaque, colored overlay?

Comment: @Nix: thanks. Not sure if I'm looking for a overlay effect. But I need the background-colour (50%) on the back and the png infront (100%)

Comment: Based on your title, the code should work. Perhaps you could make a demo and show us why it isn't.

Comment: This seems really close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182978/semi-transparent-color-layer-over-background-image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/1Ldowhn5/1/

Comment: Based on the comments I don't think this is an overlay or multiple background issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D The issue was coz I've used `opacity: 0.5;` instead of `rgba(255,0,0,0.5); ` in my css.

Comment: @Nix thanks. The issue was coz I've used `opacity: 0.5;` instead of `rgba(255,0,0,0.5); ` in my css. I was able figure out the issue while creating the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3x3y7rrq/ I'm not going to delete this post coz this might be helpful to someone in future.

Comment: @Becky If you want to improve the value of this post for future readers, I strongly suggest you edit it to include your realization or it could actually lead to more confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `opacity: 0.5;` to `background-color: rgba()` Solved the issue:

```
   .smallIcons{
        background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); // 50% background color
        background-image: url(../twiter.png); // 100% here
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

In addition, If you're using sass you can assign your colour variable as below

```
   $col_var: #f00;
   .smallIcons{
        background-color: rgba($col_var, 0.5); // 50% background color
        background-image: url(../twiter.png); // 100% here
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Posted on behalf of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Css. Easiest way to do that

```
 .class {
   background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    ),url(image.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    }
```