# How to add a color overlay to a background image?

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I have seen this question a lot both on SO and the Web. But none of them has been what I am looking for.

How do I add a color-overlay to a background image using CSS only?

Example HTML:

```
<div class="testclass">
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.testclass {
    background-image: url("../img/img.jpg");
}
```

Please note:

- I want to solve this by only using CSS. i.e I do NOT want to add a child div within the div "testclass" for the color overlay.
- This should not be a "hover effect" I want to simply just add a color-overay to the background image.
- I want to be able to use opacity i.e. I am looking for a solution that allows RGBA color.
- I am looking for just one color, lets say black. Not a gradient.

Is this possible? (I would be surprised if not, but I have not been able to find anything about this), and if so what the best way to accomplish this?

All suggestions and advice are appreciated!

Comment: a color overlay on-top of the background-image, or behind it?

Comment: If you think its a duplicate then show me a link. Because none of the other qustions I have found have had the same demands I have example not to use a child-div and solve it by only using CSS. Possible I have missed it doe...

Answer (score 400, accepted):

I see 2 easy options:

- multiple background with a translucent single gradient over image
- huge inset shadow

gradient option:

```css
    html {
      min-height:100%;
      background:linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 0, 150, 0.3), rgba(255, 0, 150, 0.3)), url(https://picsum.photos/id/1043/800/600);
      background-size:cover;
    }
```

shadow option:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1043/800/600);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 0, 150, 0.3);
}
```

an old [codepen](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wouBe) of mine with few examples

---

a third option

- [with background-blen-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode) :

> The `background-blend-mode` CSS property sets how an element's background images should blend with each other and with the element's background color.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1043/800/600) rgba(255, 0, 150, 0.3);
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Comment: `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50vw rgba(255,0,150,0.3);` is a nice option that should always cover the screen.

Comment: I suggest having min-height:100vh;

Comment: ```box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50vw rgba(255,0,150,0.3)``` is the best and most easy answer to this question a have seen for know

Comment: This is want I needed, I only needed to change: `background-blend-mode: overlay;`

Answer (score 59):

`background-image` takes multiple values.

so a combination of just 1 color linear-gradient and `css blend modes` will do the trick.

```
.testclass {
    background-image: url("../images/image.jpg"), linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

note that there is no support on IE/Edge for CSS blend-modes at all.

Comment: Better to mention the browser support tables - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

Comment: you're especially right, considering IE/Edge lacks support completely and Safari falls a bit behind. thanks for pointing out!

Comment: `background-blend-mode: multiply;` worked **best** for me with colors

Answer (score 49):

You can use a pseudo element to create the overlay.

```
.testclass {
  background-image: url("../img/img.jpg");
  position: relative;
}
.testclass:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this, it's simple and clear. I have found it from here : https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/

```
.tinted-image {

  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;

  background: 
    /* top, transparent red */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg);
}
```