# Why liner gradient is not applying to image?

Tags: html, css

linear-gradient is not showing up.

```
<div class="bg-img img-flud">
    <img style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)) url(&qout;../Movie_site/assets/img/captain-marvel-2019-10k-ym-1920x1080.jpg&qout;);  height: auto; max-width: 100%;" 
    class="img" 
    src="../Movie_site/assets/img/captain-marvel-2019-10k-ym-1920x1080.jpg" alt="">
```

need linear-gradient on that image.

Comment: JPG images aren't transparent so you can't see any background **behind it**. You'd have to **overlay** the gradient.

Comment: Just as Paulie said JPEG's are not transparent. Use `png` or `gif` for transparency and then you can see the background gradient.

Comment: missing `,` between gradient and image

Comment: you can set image in background with the gradient and set  a ratio , you can set the gradient in the parent conatiner and use mix-blend-mode https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoqNWW  or also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679649/how-to-add-a-color-overlay-to-a-background-image/36679903#36679903 not really a duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

Remove img tag.

```html
<div id='image-back'></div>
```

```css
#image-back {

background-image:
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.52), rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73)),
url('images/background.jpg');

width: 100vw;
height: auto;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `:after`

```css
.img-gradient {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-gradient:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(23,34,40,0.5) 0%, rgba(220, 66, 37, 0.5) 100%);
}

.img-gradient img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-gradient">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" width="400" />
</div>
```