# How to darken background image for body?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to darken the background image of my websites body. I have set the background size to 'cover'

```
body {
background-image: url(assets/content-images/hero.jpg);
background-size: cover;
color:'darken'
}
```

this doesnt seem to work?

Answer (score -1):

Any styling applied to the whole background for example a color will not change the shade of the background image.

There is one trick using gradients  which works quite well but it is important to have a fallback color in case of browser incompatibility, and also to make sure the text is in a contrast that will be visible over the fallback color.

Courtesy of:

[How to add a color overlay to a background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679649/how-to-add-a-color-overlay-to-a-background-image/36679903)