# background image with overlay css

Tags: css

How I design background image with overlay in CSS like this example image.

here the code. i want to add `tour` class to background image and overlay effect.

```
<div class="tour">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="image-file" alt="">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have added more information in to the question, but Is this what you want?

CSS for this:

```
.background {
  background:url('BackgroundImage.png');
}

.layer {
  background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7)
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

HTML for this:

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="layer">
  </div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @backslash Have a look at this thread - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182978/semi-transparent-color-layer-over-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

It goes something like this:

```
<style>
    .div-image{
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        background-image: url(demo.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .overlay{
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 255,0.5);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="div-image"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: i want to add image as a background.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src=".." />
</div>
```

**Style**

```
.img-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.img-wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba(37,131,173,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```