# Background-color over background-image - what's the cause?

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color, css-specificity

I have gone through weird problem (for me as a beginner in CSS world). I was trying to have a background-image with a transparent color on top of it. Image was the main page background:

```
body {

font-family: 'Raleway', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.6;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.3) url('..img/image.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

min-height: 100vh; }
```

This didn't work for me. Don't know why?

I checked the dev tools, I added separate background-color and it didn't work as well. I tried to find solution here: [Semi-transparent color layer over background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182978/semi-transparent-color-layer-over-background-image?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and treid proposed solutions. Didn't work for me.

But when I added class to the  and created this lines:

```
.body {
background: 
    linear-gradient(
    rgba(0, 0, 0,.5), 
    rgba(0, 0, 0,.5)
),
    url('../img/bg_image.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: cover; }
```

It worked! But I still don't know why?

Is it the specificity problem? Perhaps something different?
If there is someone who can ansewer my question (with qucik example) I will be grateful.

So the solution I found myslef is the code above but I don't understand whe previous attempt didn't worked form me.

Cheers,
Kamil

Comment: Because the first attempt didn't have a comma separator?

Comment: Well observed @Paulie_D! `background: rgba(0,0,0,.3), url('..img/image.jpg') no-repeat;`

Comment: background-color WILL NEVER be on the top it's always the final layer, you can only do with gradient

Comment: @Paulie_D even with comma it's not valid

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the [documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds):

> You can apply multiple backgrounds to elements. These are layered atop
>   one another with the first background you provide on top and the last
>   background listed in the back. **Only the last background can include a**
>   **background color**.

And if we check the [background property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background):

[image]

So this is not valid as background:

```css
body {
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5) ,url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
}
```

But this is valid:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0.5),rgba(255,0,0,0.5)),url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The css background property is actually a shorthand for various properties, as it is explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/).
One of those properties is the background-image, this property supports **images and gradients**,  but the important part is that it also supports [Multiple Background Images](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-image/#article-header-id-3), with this in mind you can add as many backgrounds as you like to the same element.

```
background: url(test.pnd), linear-gradient(...),...
```

In your first example you are using a

```
rgba(0, 0, 0,.5),
```

This is not a linear-gradient, neither an image is a background-color property, that is why it won't work.

A nice example for this use is the background [patterns created by Lea Verou.]

[The stacking order of multiple backgrounds](https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/), is by default the first is on top and they go down from there.
[4](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/)