# How to Overlay Image on Background in Twitter Bootstrap Section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, z-index

I have an image that I would like to overlay on top of a background gradient that I have set on a `section` element. Both the background gradient and image I am setting in CSS and calling via a class in HTML. Originally when just using the background gradient it worked fine, but after adding the image to place over the background gradient the background gradient disappeared?

```css
.banner-gradient {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #ba000b, #9e0008);
    color: white;
    z-index: 0;
    }

    .banner-overlay {
    background: url("../imagery/image.png");
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .section-align-center {
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 <section class="banner-gradient banner-overlay section-align-center">
        <div class="container">
            <p>image over background gradient</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using background-image instead of background for image.

```css
.banner-gradient:before {
 content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
}

.banner-overlay {
 background: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a') repeat;
}

.section-align-center {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner-gradient banner-overlay section-align-center">
    <div class="container">
        <p>image over background gradient</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The banner-gradient is covering the entire section, including the navbar at the top of the page.

Comment: Try using setting height to .banner-gradient:before.

Comment: Instead of setting a fixed height to .banner-gradient:before i suggest you add position relative to .banner-gradient (and a overflow hidden optionally). So the before will always be inside the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182978/semi-transparent-color-layer-over-background-image). You must first place the `banner-gradient` in your outer `div` then in your inner `div` use `banner-image`.

HTML

```
<section class="banner-gradient section-align-center">
<div class="container banner-overlay">
    <p>image over background gradient</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather edit the class of the element you want the transparency in

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="transbox">
    <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.</p>
  </div>
</div>


div.background {
    background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis.jpg') repeat;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

div.transbox {
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

div.transbox p {
    margin: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mergatroid/xkmyqjec/1/