# how can i make my class property see the whole page?

Tags: html, css

i want the whole background image to have this"rgba-indigo-light"property but i couldn't do it no matter what i tried.
actually my goal is to make the footer and container move when i zoom the page
Strangely, when I don't use this class code, my footer moves when I zoom, but my main container dont move.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/07/18/42/menu-3206749_960_720.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            min-height: 90vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            position: relative;
        }

        footer {
            margin-top: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
{% load static %}
{% include 'head.html' %}
<body>
<!-- İçerik -->
<div class="rgba-indigo-light">
    <!-- Logout Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark rgba-black-light">
                <span class="navbar-text" style="color: #F3F3F3;">
                    Hoş geldiniz, <br>{{ request.user.username }}
                </span>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex flex-row">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profil</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ml-4">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Çıkış Yap</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- container başlangıç -->
    <div class="container h-100 -flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeIn">
                <div class="text-center white-text">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>
                            <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-bold white-text wow fadeIn;"
                                data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                                <strong>Bugün ne yemek yapmak istiyorsunuz?</strong>
                            </h1>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h5 class="white-text description mb-5 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                                Sağlıklı tarifler arayın | {{ total_recipes }} Tarif
                            </h5>
                        </li>
                        <hr>
                        <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">
                            <!--Accordion wrapper-->
                            <div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist"
                                 aria-multiselectable="true">
                                <!-- Accordion card -->
                                <div class="card">
                                    <!-- Card header -->
                                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx"
                                           href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true"
                                           aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                                Gelişmiş Arama<i
                                                    class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                                            </h5>
                                            <small class="text-muted">Kategorilere Göre Filtrele</small>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Card body -->
                                    <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel"
                                         aria-labelledby="headingOne1" data-parent="#accordionEx">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <!-- Material checked -->
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="on"
                                                       id="breakfast" name="breakfast">
                                                <label class="form-check-label"
                                                       for="breakfast">Kahvalti</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="on"
                                                       id="appetizers" name="appetizers">
                                                <label class="form-check-label"
                                                       for="appetizers">Mezeler</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="on"
                                                       id="lunch" name="lunch">
                                                <label class="form-check-label"
                                                       for="lunch">Atıştırmalıklar</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="on"
                                                       id="salads" name="salads">
                                                <label class="form-check-label"
                                                       for="salads">Salatalar</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="on"
                                                       id="dinner" name="dinner">
                                                <label class="form-check-label"
                                                       for="dinner">Akşam Yemekleri</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="on"
                                                       id="dessert" name="dessert">
                                                <label class="form-check-label"
                                                       for="dessert">Tatlılar</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="on"
                                                       id="easy" name="easy">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="easy">Pratik tarif</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="on"
                                                       id="hard" name="hard">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="hard">Zor tarif</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Accordion card -->
                            <li class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                                <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                    <input type="text" id="form51" class="form-control" name="search">
                                    <label for="form51" class="">Ara</label>
                                </div>
                                <button
                                        class="btn btn-white btn-rounded btn-lg orange-text font-weight-bold ml-lg-0"
                                        type="submit">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search orange-text mr-2"
                                       aria-hidden="true"></i> Tarıfleri göster
                                </button>
                            </li>
                        </form>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="text-center" style="color: white;">
        <!-- Grid container -->
        <div class="container pt-4">
            <h3 style="background: transparent;"><strong>İLETİŞİM</strong></h3>
            <!-- Section: Social media -->
            <section class="mb-4">
                <!-- Facebook -->
                <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating text-dark m-1"
                   href="" role="button"
                   data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>

                <!-- Twitter -->
                <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating text-dark m-1" href=""
                   role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="white"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <!-- Instagram -->
                <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating text-dark m-1"
                   href="" role="button"
                   data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <!-- Linkedin -->
                <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating text-dark m-1"
                   href="" role="button"
                   data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <!-- Github -->
                <a class="btn btn-link btn-floating text-dark m-1" href="https://github.com/newdeveloperb4ha"
                   role="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
            </section>
            <!-- Section: Social media -->
        </div>
        <!-- Grid container -->
        <!-- Copyright -->
        <div class="text-center p-3 navbar-dark" style="color: white;">
            © 2023 Copyright:
            <a class="text-white" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000">CelebiF00D.com</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Copyright -->
    </footer>
    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
    <script>
        // Animation init
        new WOW().init();
        // Material Select Initialization
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.mdb-select').material_select();
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to write the code in head and body but then it doesn't get the whole page
I finished the div under the footer but I don't know if I did it right
its my photo link its 50% zoom https://prnt.sc/OOY6E-hzk1dR and its 100%zoom https://prnt.sc/yVBERazDGGQf.

Comment: Your `<div>` has a `class` called `rgba-indigo-light`, but what are you expecting that class to do and why?  The CSS shown has no rules for that class.

Comment: I want it to be the same color as the other side when I zoom in.@david

Comment: I _think_ this is what you're looking to achieve, [try the last method in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182978/semi-transparent-color-layer-over-background-image/71802275#71802275)